# Can't get beyond a 2MB file upload limit in my form

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to alter the upload_max_filesize to 4M using .htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 4M
```

But PHP continues to cap the size at 2M

```
upload_max_filesize 2M 2M
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your PHP/Apache installation allow the changing of values through `.htaccess`? What does your server setup look like?

Comment: I have the ability to do mod-rewrites, etc.  in .htaccess if that helps answer your question.

Comment: I am running LAMP -- cPanel/WHM with root level access on a virtual server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value upload_max_filesize 4M
</IfModule>
```

(a) Need to put the setting in a IfModule container
(b) need to put the .htaccess file in the document root

Or at least that's how I got it to work...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the htaccess try with:

```
<?php
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "4M");
?>
```

I don't know if it works but it can be a workaround

Comment: I'll try... I don;t think it will work because according to the php.ini documentation, this can only be altered via .htaccess or httpdconf

Answer (score 0):

As mck89 suggested, try using `ini_set` - if you're on a shared host you might need to use that function or place a php.ini file somewhere as not all hosts allow using .htaccess to set PHP configuration.

Comment: How can I determine if my host allows me to use .htaccess to alter php.ini configs?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at your [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) setting as it also affects upload size limits.

Comment: Thanks Archimedix...it's set at 8M. More than sufficient for my app.